# Angularjs link ng-model to isolated scope in directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I want a small attribute directive, that would allow me to dynamically change constraints on a input element it is attached to. The usage would be like so:

```
<input type="text" ui-constraints-field data-ng-model="mydata" data-constraints="myconstraints" />
```

And in the controller:

```
$scope.mydata = "test string";
$scope.myconstraints = [{key: "required", value: "true"}];
```

Mind that the data or constraints can change at any time. So I have written this:

```
myApp.directive('uiConstraintsField', [function(){

    function applyConstraints(scope, element){
        //remove old constraints
        if(scope.old !== undefined && scope.old !== null){
            for (var i = 0; i < scope.old.length; i++) {
                element.removeAttr(scope.old[i].key);
            }
        }

        //apply new constraints
        if(scope.constraints !== undefined && scope.constraints !== null){
            for (var i = 0; i < scope.constraints.length; i++) {
                var constraint = scope.constraints[i];
                element.attr(constraint.key, constraint.value);
            }
        }

        //newly passed constraints now will be old constraints
        scope.old = scope.constraints;
    }

    return {
        restrict : 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope : {
            constraints : '=constraints'
        },
        link : function(scope, element, attrs){
            scope.old = scope.constraints;
            scope.$watch("constraints", function(){
                applyConstraints(scope, element);
            });
        }
    };

}]);
```

Constraints are being updated correctly, however model is not linked. How do I link the model so `mydata` is displayed and updated in the textbox? Thanks :)

--EDIT--
I am using angular v 1.0.3 and I can't change it to newer. This seems to be causing the issue.
[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/gcDUR76lLGX5oTUV3eAo?p=preview)

Comment: It seems to be linked, unless i understand the issue incorrectly..

Comment: I am not sure what is going on, but the value of mydata is not displayed in the textbox. And if I type something in the textbox, mydata is not getting updated with that value. So I assume it is not linked.

Comment: Add the `$scope` service to your directive dependencies and check again.

Comment: Remeber 4th argument in the link function will be ngModelController, which will have the value of the model.. Are you trying to access scope.myData within the directive?

Comment: no I don't, I do not want to touch the mydata, I just want it to be updated and displayed within the textbox that's it. the directive is there purely to update the constraints.

Comment: _How do I link the model so mydata is displayed and updated in the textbox?_ : I see mydata displayed here... http://plnkr.co/edit/CNA4vt?p=preview

Comment: @PSL -> ok, I am puzzled now, works on plnkr but not on my page, gotta investigate :/

Comment: Try to update the plunker to replicate the issue. Do you have an ng-repeat or something? Also try to remove the directive from the element and see if your binding is getting updated as well... It doesnot look like directive has anything to do with your issue.

Comment: I did, I am using Angularjs version 1.0.3 and can't change it to newer... http://plnkr.co/edit/gcDUR76lLGX5oTUV3eAo?p=preview

Comment: You will need to use $compile on the element every time your constraints change to allow angular to update

Comment: Thanks all for help, I have solved the problem another way (see my answer) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so there is a better solution to the one I have posted in my initial post, and this one works in older versions of Angular (1.0.3 in my case) as well as in the latest one. Here it is:

```
myApp.directive('uiConstraints', [function(){

    function applyConstraints(element, newVal, oldVal){
        //remove old constraints
        if(oldVal !== undefined && oldVal !== null){
            for (var i = 0; i < oldVal.length; i++) {
                element.removeAttr(oldVal[i].key);
            }
        }

        //apply new constraints
        if(newVal !== undefined && newVal !== null){
            for (var i = 0; i < newVal.length; i++) {
                var constraint = newVal[i];
                element.attr(constraint.key, constraint.value);
            }
        }
    }

    function link(scope, element, attrs){
        scope.$watch(attrs.uiConstraints, function(newVal, oldVal){
            applyConstraints(element, newVal, oldVal);
        });
    }

    return {
        restrict : 'A',
        link : link
    };

}]);
```

The usage of such directive would be like so:

```
<textarea ui-constraints="myConstraints" ng-model="myData" />
```

with appropriate values (myConstraints and myData) declared in the controller.
Thanks everyone for trying to help :)